# Is it possible to query a one-to-many with one query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Lets take stackoverflow as an example:

**Post**

```
Postid          Title          Mess
--------------------------------------------------
1               Title1         This is a question
2               Title2         This is a question1
3               Title3         This is a question2
4               Title4         This is a question3
5               Title5         This is a question4
6               Title6         This is a question5
```

**Tags**

```
TagId     PostId     Name
-----------------------------
1         1              Tag1
2         1              Tag2
3         1              Tag3
4         1              Tag4
5         2              Tag5
6         3              Tag6
7         4              Tag7
8         5              Tag8
9         6              Tag9
10        3              Tag10
```

In this design how would I get all the questions with its associated tags in one query. is this even possible?

****Edit****

```
select t.*, p.* from Tags t
join post p on t.postid=p.postid
```

Something like this would give me all the tags for each question. But I don't think this is efficient. What do you think.

Comment: you mean joins? check out http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Comment: Can you show what you want as output from your one query? "get all the questions with its associated tags" is rather vague and ambiguous.

Comment: If you know all tags upfront and would rather not deal with multiple results per post, you could use [pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx).

Comment: @Aaron - I am not sure what kind of output to expect on something like this. But, I got an idea maybe I can query the tags table then join the post table and get the id, title and message. If I do this then there will be duplicate data in the results for the post table. is this effiecient?

Comment: Well, can you tell us what you would ideally like to see?

Comment: What do you think would be more efficient? This is becoming less of a question as you add more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your example is very weak. You shouldn't have the tag name in the table you use to join posts and tags.

You should have the following tables:

- Posts: **PostId**, Title, Mess
- Tags: **TagId**, Name
- Posts_Tags: **PostId**, **TagId**

If you don't do this then you'll have many equal tag names when 2 posts have the same tag, do you see?

Now, in order to query these tables and get all questions with the associated tags you should do the following:

```
select * from posts p
join posts_tags pt on p.postId = pt.postId
join tags on pt.tagId = t.tagId
```

You can say it is less efficient but you're not considering data duplication in your example, which may cause serious errors.

Comment: Thanks I needed that clarification